# How to downgrade mono from 6.x to 5.x or 4.x?

Tags: mono, downgrade

After upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 (passing through 20.04) an old web application with an ASMX web service (so with Mono ) won't work anymore.
I tried a lot of things , but neither works.
Mono error is: "Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION"

This error didn't happen as soon as i used old Mono version with Ubuntu 18.04.

My VPS hosting don't support Ubuntu 18.04 anymore, so I'm asking you how can I downgrade Mono.

Currently Ubuntu setup is:

Ubuntu 22.04 kernel 5.15

Apache 2.4.52

Php 7.4

Mono 6.8

I think that using old Mono version (4.x or 5.x) I could make work that asmx web service again.

Thanks

Comment: Unless someone maintains a PPA somewhere, you likely will need to attempt compiling it yourself.

Comment: Have you considered docker containers or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ and follow the instructions to add their repositories for Ubuntu 18.04.  After running the `apt update` step, you will have those versions of mono available to install via `apt`.

You can also browse their repository manually if it's easier for you to find what you want.  Just direct your browser to https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/.  If you're not familiar with how `apt` repos work, you can look under https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists for index files.  These are text files that list what packages they have made available for a particular distribution/version.  Each block of text is like the output from `apt show`, for example,

```
Source: mono-basic
Version: 4.7-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Debian Mono Group <pkg-mono-group@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 469
Depends: libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1)
Homepage: http://www.mono-project.com/Visual_Basic
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Filename: pool/main/m/mono-basic/libmono-cecil-vb0.9-cil_4.7-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb
Size: 149176
SHA256: 6ff813170a85dd11f210c70a2ebe5cd6c9d7b964fe4f54addc24d54e58fe5095
SHA1: d72e40410337822020cc191a575592baa7cf309d
MD5sum: 6474364d238ddf60e8817ef4c0300114
Description: Visual Basic 2012 Cecil libraries for Mono
 This package contains the Cecil libraries for the Mono Visual Basic library,
 aimed at the specifications / features of the Visual Basic 2012.
 .
 Mono is a platform for running and developing applications based on the
 ECMA/ISO Standards. Mono is an open source effort led by Novell.
 Mono provides a complete CLR (Common Language Runtime) including compiler and
 runtime, which can produce and execute CIL (Common Intermediate Language)
 bytecode (aka assemblies), and a class library.
```

The `filename` line tells you where to find the actual `.deb` file relative to the server root.  Here, it would be https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mono-basic/libmono-cecil-vb0.9-cil_4.7-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb.  That said, once you've found the thing you want in the package file, you can also just `apt-get install mono-basic`, and the package manager will take care of the rest.